# How to hierarchically sort columns?

Tags: unix, sorting

How can I sort by 2 separate columns? for example, I want sort by column 6 first, then sort by column 4

```
 column4  column5    column6
 lae2894      603    user1
 e2894       2096    user1
 e2894       2096    user1
 e2894       2096    user1
 lae2894      603    user1
 lae2894      603    user1
```

Those have been sorted by the following command:

```
sort -t, -k6 users.txt > sorted-user.txt
```

But the output I want should look like this:

```
 column4      column5      column6
 e2894            603        user1
 e2894           2096        user1
 e2894           2096        user1
 laee2894        2096        user1
 lae2894          603        user1
 lae2894          603        user1
```

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow, but what software or programming language are you talking about?

Comment: He is talking about unix sort tool.

Comment: @phresnel unix/linux shell

Comment: @XapaJIaMnu: But you are making assumptions, these might also be commands of a funky new programming language. Your second assumption is on her/his/its gender ;)

Comment: @phresnel, give the dash commands and the > for redirected output, I am most certainly not making assumptions...

Answer (score 1):

Most versions of `sort` allow multiple key specifications. Try this:

```
sort -t, -k6,6 -k4,4 input.txt
```

I'm assuming that your actual input file uses `,` as a separator, since you specified that in your example command (which means the "example" data you've pasted isn't really representative of your file...). Also note that a key specification with only a single number (like your `-k6`) means a single key that starts in that field and extends to the end of line, so in order to specify a single field to sort on, you need to use the syntax above.

Answer (score 1):

The `-k` option for `sort` can appear multiple times.  Try:

```
sort -t, -k6,6 -k4,4 inputfile
```

See [sort invocation](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html) for more.

```
> ‘-k pos1[,pos2]’
> ‘--key=pos1[,pos2]’

Specify a sort field that consists of the part of the line between pos1 and pos2 (or the end of the line, if pos2 is omitted), inclusive. 
Each pos has the form ‘f[.c][opts]’, where f is the number of the field to use, and c is the number of the first character from the beginning of the field. Fields and character positions are numbered starting with 1; a character position of zero in pos2 indicates the field's last character. If ‘.c’ is omitted from pos1, it defaults to 1 (the beginning of the field); if omitted from pos2, it defaults to 0 (the end of the field). opts are ordering options, allowing individual keys to be sorted according to different rules; see below for details. Keys can span multiple fields. 

Example: To sort on the second field, use --key=2,2 (-k 2,2). See below for more notes on keys and more examples. See also the --debug option to help determine the part of the line being used in the sort.
```